# SQL query convert

Tags: sql

This works absolutely fine

```
Update TradeFlow 
set flt_TotalPriceUSD= 
(Select top 1 (flt_ExRate * TradeFlow.flt_TotalPrice) 
from ExchangeRate ex inner join DateConversion dc 
on ex.dtm_Date = dc.gDate and  pDate=Convert(varchar,'01') + '/' 
+  Convert(varchar,'03') + '/' + Convert(varchar,'1389'))
```

but when I substitute it with values from the database (`TradeFlow.int_Month` and `TradeFlow.int_Year`) it stops working. `pdate` is a string

```
Update TradeFlow 
set flt_TotalPriceUSD = (Select top 1 (flt_ExRate * TradeFlow.flt_TotalPrice)
from ExchangeRate ex inner join DateConversion dc   
on ex.dtm_Date = dc.gDate and  pDate=Convert(varchar,'01') + '/' +  
Convert(varchar,TradeFlow.int_Month) + '/' 
+ Convert(varchar,TradeFlow.int_Year))
```

any idea why ?

Comment: stop working means not fetching the right result

Comment: What error do you get? Your top query is converting an nvarchar value to an nvarchar value, anyway, so it won't error

Comment: can you post some rows from the TradeFlow table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

Instead of:

```
Convert(varchar,TradeFlow.int_Month) ...
Convert(varchar,TradeFlow.int_Year))
```

write:

```
right( '0' + rtrim(ltrim(str(TradeFlow.int_Month))), 2) ...
right( '0000' + rtrim(ltrim(str(TradeFlow.int_Year))), 4) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update TradeFlow 
set flt_TotalPriceUSD= (Select top 1 (flt_ExRate * TradeFlow.flt_TotalPrice) 
    from ExchangeRate ex inner join DateConversion dc   
on ex.dtm_Date = dc.gDate and  
    --if pDate is varchar type (`dd/MM/yyyy`)
    pDate= '01/' + right('0' + cast(TradeFlow.int_Month as varchar), 2) + '/' + 
        cast(TradeFlow.int_Year as varchar)

    --if pDate is datetime type
    pDate=  cast(TradeFlow.int_Year as varchar) + 
        right('0' + cast(TradeFlow.int_Month as varchar), 2) + '01'
```

Comment: I think that varchar is varchar(1). Perhaps your casth should be to varchar(2). It is not? Sorry if not, I talk from my memory.

Comment: Actually, according to [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), it's `varchar(30)` in the context of a CAST or CONVERT: *When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30*